# Detect outliers in a survey with Pythons Scikit-Learn lib

Tags: python, scikit-learn, outliers

I have made a dummy dataset of a'survey'. Survey has 5 questions and each question has 5 different answers (1,2,3,4,5). My goal is to find determinate if someone gave random answers on the survey (answer without thinking). I have tried to determinate these outliers with some algorithms in 'scikit-learn', but i do not like my results, they are very random. 
This is my dataset:

https://www.sendspace.com/file/8gjqf6

Dataset has 5 columns for questions, 1 column that represent time in seconds that someone took to answer all 5 questions, and column `result`.
'Result' column is done by hand/by me (you will see that i put the `BOT` next to answers that are given with less then 7 seconds, and that are all the same).

There is 58 rows, each row represent one person that did a survey and that gave the answer to 5 questions. My goal is to find person / row that did not take the survey 'seriously' . That means that he/she did not even read the question but he/she just put the random answers (or answered on every question 1,1,1,1,1 or any other number, or did 1,2,3,4,5...).

Function `def calc(col):`  is for checking the accuracy.

What can I do to improve this code?

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.covariance import EllipticEnvelope
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM
from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor

# I put the 'result' my hand

df = pd.read_csv('pitanja.csv')
#print(df)


x = df.iloc[:,:-1]

out_cls = [['SVM rbf', OneClassSVM(kernel='rbf', gamma='scale')],
           ['SVM lin', OneClassSVM(kernel='linear', gamma='scale')],
           ['SVM sigm', OneClassSVM(kernel='sigmoid', gamma='scale')],
            ['SVM poly2', OneClassSVM(kernel='poly', gamma='scale',degree=2)],
            ['SVM poly3', OneClassSVM(kernel='poly', gamma='scale', degree=3)],
            ['Isol For', IsolationForest(contamination = 'auto', behaviour = 'new')],
            ['Ell Env', EllipticEnvelope(store_precision=True, assume_centered=False)]]

r = df
for out in out_cls:

    cls = out[1]
    model = cls.fit(x)
    prediction = model.predict(x)

    result = []
    for i in prediction:
        if i == -1:
            result.append('BOT')

        else:
            result.append('good')

    r[out[0]] = result

result = r[['result','SVM rbf','SVM lin','SVM sigm','SVM poly2','SVM poly3','Isol For','Ell Env']]
print(result)

# to determinate % of matching (accuracy)
def calc(col):

    lenght = len(result)

    num = 0
    for i,j in zip(result['result'], result[col]):

        if i == j:
            num+=1

    res = 'Matching wiht ' + col + ': ' +str(round((num/lenght)*100,2)) + '%'

    return res

print(calc('SVM rbf'))
print(calc('SVM lin'))
print(calc('SVM sigm'))
print(calc('SVM poly2'))
print(calc('SVM poly3'))
print(calc('Isol For'))
print(calc('Ell Env'))
```

Comment: Imagine that you are doing the survey online, but you do not care about what are you going to answer, so you just click on random answers on the question (without reading the questions or reading the answers)

Comment: Ok, is there a way to find randomness in dataset?
Look at the dataset I provided, my goal is to find answer/s (row/s) that someone gave without reading the questions.

Comment: Can you show me the example